# Virtual on-screen keyboard for raspberry pi touch screen

Tags: keyboard, gui, tkinter

The following is simple code that accepts a line of text from a user:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root= Tk()
entry= ttk.Entry(root, width=30)
entry.pack()
```

[image: text box]

I  am running this code on a raspberry pi using an external keyboard with a 7 inch touch display.  But what I want is that as soon as I click in the text field a simple on-screen keyboard pops up and I am able to enter a string using this keyboard via the touch panel.

I want to know what  are the different approaches to accomplish this.   Specifically I need a simple small size on-screen keyboard that only needs to have letters a-z.

Answer (score 2):

There're a few different keyboard solutions. Two of the most popular are `matchbox-keyboard` and `florence`. For `matchbox-keyboard`, they have a library to interact with auto-hide and auto-show. `florence` attempts to detect when it should auto-hide and doesn't seem to support auto-show. I'm still looking for an ideal solution myself.

Comment: Throwing in a plug for onboard as another keyboard option which is more modern & configureable IMHO

Answer (score -1):

You could use matchbox keyboard: `sudo apt install matchbox-key`